# Angular - TypeError Cannot set _id to Null Value

Tags: node.js, angular

Has a transaction function that worked in first pass and at 2nd pass, got "TypeError: Cannot set _id to Null value.  Both passes were to create a new transaction. Besides, system seemed to indicate that there was value for variable that was being used to assign to_id.  In this case,

print"this.selectedLeave_id" and saw value as expected.  However, Angular right away in next statement complaining that Null value was set to "this.SLTran.leave_id".

Below pls find code and any help is appreciated.

```
onSubmitLeaveTran() 
{           
  if (this.selectedLeaveTran_id != 0) // means first loaded all trans and then select from table to modify
  { 
    this.sLTran = this.tempSLTran;  // tempSLTran was from row selected to be modified
    this.sLTran.leaveType = this.tempLeaveType; // from dialog box edited data
    this.sLTran.leaveStartDate = this.tempLeaveStartDate; // from dialog box edited data
    this.sLTran.leaveEndDate = this.tempLeaveEndDate; // from dialog box edited data
    this.sLTran.numDaysRequested = this.tempNumDaysRequested; // from dialog box edited data
    console.log('2-2.5 inside onSubmit Leave Tran for update :',this.sLTran);
    this.staffLeaveDataSvc.updateSLTran(this.sLTran).subscribe((sLTran:staffLeaveTran) => {this.sLTran = sLTran});
  }
  else
  {  // a new tran
    console.log('2-2.4 inside onSubmit Leave Tran selectedLeave_id for new tran:',this.selectedLeave_id);
    this.sLTran.leave_id = this.selectedLeave_id; // first established the leave_id associated with this new tran
    this.sLTran.leaveType = this.tempLeaveType;
    this.sLTran.leaveStartDate = this.tempLeaveStartDate;
    this.sLTran.leaveEndDate = this.tempLeaveEndDate;
    this.sLTran.numDaysRequested = this.tempNumDaysRequested;
    this.staffLeaveDataSvc.addSLTran(this.sLTran).subscribe(
      (sLTran:staffLeaveTran) => {
        this.sLTran = sLTran
    });
  }      
};
```

Comment: did you initialize this.sLTran ?

Comment: thanks for help.  It was initialized as "SLTran:StaffLeaveTran = new staffLeaveTran(_);  Hope this is the correct way to initialize. Q too, if initialization was an issue, why first pass was successful but not 2nd pass?